# WPF/XAML Layout of two Labels containing different length text whilst maintaining equal size Font Scaling

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts, scaling

I'm trying position two labels, one right next to the other (with a small amount of spacing).

e.g.

Label 1  Label 2

the content of each label will always be different, most often Label 2 will have more characters but I want the content to scale as the window is resized and I want the font sizes in Label 1 and Label 2 to remain consistent.

I don't care if the contents of Label 2 are cropped if too long.

I've tried using a grid with two columns and placed the Label inside a ViewBox:

```
<Viewbox Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Label Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Path=Suburb}"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Problem with this is, the positioning is never right and the font sizes don't remain consistent.

What is the best layout method to achieve this? Can I synchronise the font sizes through binding? I've tried binding Label 2's FontSize property to Label 1's FontSize but that doesn't work as it just returns 12 every time no matter how big/small the font really is (I'm presuming the actual FontSize isn't being calculated because the Label is inside a ViewBox).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

```
<Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Second" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    <TextBlock Text="First" />
  </DockPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

Note that the second label would never get cropped since the `Viewbox` would allow the content to render to any size and then scale it. You can specify `MaxWidth` on the second `TextBlock` which would limit its size in pixels.

Instead of a `DockPanel` you can use a `Grid` with different `ColumnDefinitions` to achieve the same effect.

The important thing is that they're all in the same `Viewbox` (which, consequently, doesn't synchronize the `FontSize` but performs a visual scaling of everything it contains).

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting - I'll give this a shot now.

Comment: Not 100% what I was after, but it probably achieves a good enough result. Can you think of how I can get the Second textbox to trim overhanging characters - at the moment if there is a lot of text in both Second and First, the font will scale down infinately, i'd like to see if i could achieve a minimum font size if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The following markup seems to be ok:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox>
        <Label Content="Label 1" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=label2}"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
        <Label Name="label2" Content="Label 2 Label 2 Label 2"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Try resizing the window up/down and at the same time, adjust the content of Label 2 be longer than Label 1 - e.g. "Label 2 Label 2 Label 2". When you resize, does the font size remain the same in both Labels?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you. I got it and fixed. Please see my rewritten answer

Comment: The problem I see with this is, the width of Label 1 will be the same as the width of Label 2, so there will be a larger than desired space between them. There will be a heap of whitespace after Label 1.

Comment: You can set HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" for the first Label

Comment: would this move the white space from the right to the left side of the Label?

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure of what 'content scale as the window resizes' and 'font sizes remain consistent' actuall means, but I guess you want each label to trim depending on available space.

So why not use `TextBlock` as below

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Suburb}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Area}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Scaling - as in when the window grows bigger through resizing or opening on larger monitors, the content within the window should scale proportionally bigger. Similarly, when the window is smaller, the content within the window should becomes proportionally smaller.

Comment: but if the font size has to remain the same, then you are not really scaling, but trimming text to the available space

Comment: But I'm only trimming text in label 2 and only if the text length exceeds the available space. Where the font scaling is critical is is when our application is opened at say 384x683 it has to be a smaller font, by comparison it will also be opened at 768x1366 and 1080x1920. Simply applying a set font size doesn't satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is old, but one of the more correct ways to do this is to use **Runs**.

Runs are sections of text within a TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Run Text="{Binding Suburb}" />
    <Run Text="{Binding Area}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Keep in mind that everything within a TextBlock is whitespace-sensitive, so if you wanted to have two Runs back-to-back without any space in between, you would do something like this:

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Run Text="Foo" /><Run Text="bar" />
    <!-- Prints 'Foobar' -->
</TextBlock>
```

It's similar to how HTML is rendered, if there is whitespace between the tags, a single space is rendered on the page between those elements. This rule only applies to items *within* a TextBlock, not the entire XAML page.